# Word macro to extract ceratin pages and save them separately

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, macros

I am using Word 2016.

I have a 245 page document but only need to save the pages (about 15) that have word SUMMARY present on the page. This is usually on the second or third line of the page.

These pages need to be moved to a new document and saved in new document, preferably pdf format. I can do this in several manual steps but was hoping for some help for a macro to do this?